# Correct way of invoking an api gateway with json payload and binary data

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I need to develop an API Gateway that received a binary file and some additional information (you can consider them as metadata: original filename plus description)

What's the correct way in AWS? Encode the binary as Base64 or is there a more efficient way?
The first way I know how to do, but I don't know if in AWS world it's the correct way

Thanks

Comment: HI, I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: yes my friend, I've converted to base64 then passed as payload then converted back